# Typo3 Exception - No suitable request handler found

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

so i was on vacation for 5 Days and when i came back our Website (Typo 3 - 7.6.25) was "broke".
If i try to go on the page i get the following Error:

```
#1205414233: No suitable request handler found.

TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Exception thrown in file
/html/typo3/typo3_src-7.6.25/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Mvc/RequestHandlerResolver.php in line 83.
```

Neither me nor anyone else in my company changed something on the Typo3 Website in the past 5 Days.

I've tried to search for Solutions but neither of them helped.
Sadly we have no Backups (This will be Priority 1 after this).
I've also found a Typo3 Website talking about that problem here: https://wiki.typo3.org/Exception/CMS/1205414233
but i dont know where to include the code given by this Site.

Does anyone know what I can do with this Error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

first of all TYPO3 7.6.25 is from 13.03.2018. The last free release is 7.6.32 from 11.12.2018. There are many security updates since your version. If you buy ELTS you can download and install 7.6.41 ELTS (28.01.2020) Maybe this will help with your problem.

Other things you can check: Hosting Provider changes php version or mysql? I really think you should try update to TYPO3 8.7 and test again. Backup your site befor update.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. I cant update Typo3 at the time. We have to many Extensions made for this Version.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this can have different reasons. In my case (in TYPO3 8.7) the problem was triggered from comments in TypoScript. I've used a (valid!) multi line comment:

```
plugin.tx_myplugin {
  settings {
    firstsetting = 1
    /*secondsetting = 2
    thirdsetting = 3*/
  }
}
```

In the "TypoScript Object Browser" there was a warning, it seems TYPO3 had problems parsing TypoScript due to this comment.